# Setting an Environment Value in a FOR Loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I wrote this code:

```
set list1=This,Is,A,List
set list2=

FOR %%c IN (%list1%) DO set list2=%list2%-%%c
```

I expected list2 to equal -This-Is-A-List, instead it equals -List. I have verified that it is not "remembering" the value from the last iteration of the loop. I also tried this code:

```
setx list1 This,Is,A,List
setx list2 ""

FOR %%c IN (%list1%) DO setx list2 %list2%-%%c
```

And got much the same result. Is there a way to set an environment variable in a command FOR such that it will accumulate while the FOR is iterating?

Comment: Read about [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Please add it as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate in terms of the issue, though I doubt I would have read that one, even if I had found it, because my use case appeared to be pretty different. Still I would not fight you marking this as a duplicate.